# How to traverse this keyed multidimensional array in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have following array:

```
<?php
$cars = array(
            "cars" => array
                (
                    array("make" => "Volvo", "model" => "2018", "price" => 31.91),
                    array("make" => "BMW", "model" => "2015", "price" => 34.50),
                    array("make" => "Toyota", "model" => "2019", "price" => 27.58)
                )
            );

echo "<pre>";
print_r($cars);
echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Human readable form:

```
Array
(
    [cars] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [make] => Volvo
                    [model] => 2018
                    [price] => 31.91
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [make] => BMW
                    [model] => 2015
                    [price] => 34.5
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [make] => Toyota
                    [model] => 2019
                    [price] => 27.58
                )

        )

)
```

How can we traverse this array to get every elements? Is it necessary to use OUTER `foreach` loop to get access inside `cars` array? Can we not access them directly if we already knew about the key in advance?

I am using following approach:

```
<?php
foreach($cars as $key => $array)
{
    echo "Key: " . $key;
    echo "<hr />";
    foreach($array as $sub_key => $sub_array)
    {
        echo "Make:" . $sub_array['make'];
        echo "<br />";
        echo "Model:" . $sub_array['model'];
        echo "<br />";
        echo "Price:" . $sub_array['price'];
        echo "<hr />";
    }
}
?>
```

Output:

```
Key: cars

Make:Volvo
Model:2018
Price:31.91

Make:BMW
Model:2015
Price:34.5

Make:Toyota
Model:2019
Price:27.58
```

How to traverse array elements without using outer `foreach` loop? I mean without using

```
foreach($cars as $key => $array)
```

**EDIT**

I don't think it is duplicate to those questions in any means. My question is to avoid the need of outer loop and not the inner loop.

Comment: Like `foreach($cars['cars'] as $key => $array)`?

Comment: @JonStirling Yes right, but if we don't know the key or key is not always same then we can't use this method?

Comment: Is there only ever going to be one key, even if you don't know what it is?

Comment: You could always use $cars[0] to get the first element inside the array (which may or may not have the key 'cars'). Is there any specific reason that you don't want to use the outer foreach loop? If you explain why you want this, we may be able to help you better.

Comment: @FabianGillenius yes right. There is no specific reason for not to use outer foreach loop. I thought if we have two or more outer keys e.g. cars, jeeps,... etc. then we must have to use outer foreach loop but if we have only one key cars then there is no need to loop it; we can just access the array using $cars['cars'].

Comment: In that case, there is really no reason to do away with the outer loop. Compared to checking the number of items in the array and assigning a single item to a variable, the difference in resource cost is negligible. It's entirely possible that doing the outer loop will always be less costly than doing a more complex "if then else" operation. It also keeps your code more readable, which should always be a top priority. Unless you have another reason, I suggest you keep your code as it is.